# Get address of double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

I'm trying to figure out the correct syntax in this situation:

- Assign double pointer to an object
- Get the original address of that double pointer back

Here's a code example:

```
typedef struct obj2{
  obj1 **ptr;
} obj2;

void func(obj1 **dbl)
{
    obj2 *tmp = malloc(sizeof(obj2));

    printf("before; dbl address is %p\n", (void*)&dbl); // 0x7fff6a1362a0
    tmp->ptr = dbl;

    // here; trying to print the same address as the first printf
    printf("after; dbl address is %p\n", (void*)(tmp->ptr)); // 0x7fff6a136280
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The use case for this is so I can use `dbl` elsewhere in the codebase, so the ultimate goal here is just to be able to correctly pass around a double pointer.

Comment: Problem is that `tmp->ptr` **doesn't have the same address as** `dbl`. They are different objects with the same contents. The address of `dbl` will (typically) be on the stack, whereas `tmp->ptr` will be somewhere on the heap.

Comment: In the first printf you are taking the address of a ** so you get in fact a ***. Just print dbl there.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve. What maks you think that you are actually doing something wrong? Can you demonstrate that with a [mre]?

Comment: You can't get the address of `dbl` from `tmp->ptr`. `tmp->ptr` has the same value as `dbl` but they are two distinct variables. Just like any other two variables you can't get the address of a variable just by knowing the value and address of another variable.

Comment: I need to access `dbl` elsewhere in the codebase, which is why I'm doing `tmp->ptr = dbl`. That way, I can get it other places with `tmp->ptr`. The problem is that I'm getting errors when trying to use `tmp->ptr` elsewhere -- it's doesn't seem to be referencing it correctly.

Comment: tmp->ptr is a void**, not logically the same as a void*. You need to dereference it once to get the result you expect.

Answer (score 0):

`&dbl` is the address of the parameter `dbl` which is a local variable.

```
tmp->ptr = dbl;
```

Assigns the `tmp->ptr` with the value `dbl` holds, not the address of the variable `dbl`. Those addresses most likely to be different inless you assign `dbl` with `&dbl` (it makes no sense at all).

Comment: "Assigns the `tmp->ptr` with the value `dbl` holds" - since `dbl` is a double pointer, are you saying `tmp->ptr` will have `*dbl`?

Comment: @robl - no, I think you need to exercise a bit pointers as they are some king of woodoo black magic for you.

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
tmp->ptr = dbl;
```

you are not assigning the address of the pointer db1 to the object `tmp->ptr`. You are assigning the value stored in the pointer.

So these two calls of printf output different values

```
printf("before; dbl address is %p\n", (void*)&dbl); // 0x7fff6a1362a0

// here; trying to print the same address as the first printf
printf("after; dbl address is %p\n", (void*)(tmp->ptr)); // 0x7fff6a136280
```

You should change the first call of printf the following way

```
printf("before; dbl address is %p\n", (void*)dbl);
```